# See h1 tag over picture in html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website for a school project and I have made a slideshow of pictures but the thing is I want a `h1` tag over the picture but it does not work!

I have tried changing all sorts of thing but no success.
The following is the code snippet:

```css
#slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#slideshow h1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="slideshow">
  <h1>Space</h1>
  <figure class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      <img class="img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      <img class="img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
   </figure> 
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

css:

```
#slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  position:relative;
}
#slideshow h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 5px; //offet from left side to be more legible   
}
```

Comment: You can also use a figcaption to your figure, @McKHAANNN please select any of the answers as answered if it solved your issue.

Comment: @iamwtk I have one more question, why does not text-align: center; work?

Comment: For h1? Because it is absolute positioned, so the block is as big as text inside. Make width 100% and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `#slideshow` `position: relative` because an element (e.g. your h1) with `position: absolute` will be positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor.

[position-CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute)

Answer (score 0):

you just need set position #slideshow h1 from absolute to relative

```css
#slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#slideshow h1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<section id="slideshow">
  <h1>TESTING</h1>
  <figure class="img-container">
      <img class="img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      <img class="img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
      <img class="img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
   </figure> 
</section>
```

Comment: That will not work, the text will be over the pictures then. I have the solutions now!  but thanks anyways for trying to help me!

Comment: i thnk u ask about how to set h1 over the picture? am i wrong?

Comment: No I ment over the picture not above! easy to missunderstand :D

Comment: it's ok then :D

Answer (score -1):

This is a very simple problem. I will teach you how to do it in a snap! You need to change the z-index on the slideshow to 0 and the h1 to 1. This means that the h1 will be on top of the slideshow section. Z-index is the Z axis positioning of elements.

```
#slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 0;
}
#slideshow h1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: z-index is possible only on elements where the position is set. in your example you are missing positioning on #slideshow, so the z-index is there completely useless.

Comment: That is the modified code that the "owner" posted. This is just a more simple way.